# How can we use Automapper 10 in Extension Method?

Tags: .net-core, automapper

We have used  Old version of Automapper in Static Class and Extension method

```
  public static Account GetAccountDomain(this AccountViewModel viewModel)
    {
        return AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<AccountViewModel, Account>(viewModel);
    }
```

and we had used this without caring about the technology of mapping in Domain and command Handler and Query Handler as following

```
  accountViewModel.GetAccountDomain();
```

what can we do in dot net core and automapper 10 ?

Comment: What did you try and what problems did you face?

Comment: We can not use this structure in new version of Automapper in dot net core 3.1

Answer (score 1):

Automapper has removed Static state for better performance. It should use with DI Pattern(IMapper) in all of framework that you need.